# $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu((A-x) \cap B)d\mu = \mu(A)\mu(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given two measurable subsets $A, B$ of $\mathbb{R}$, I want to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu((A-x) \cap B)d\mu =  \mu(A)\mu(B)$, where $A-x = \{a-x : a \in A\}$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. All I can think of is that $\mu(A) = \mu(A-x)$, because that's just translation, and that I might somehow set up an integral to use the Fubini theorem for this one, since the product $\mu(A)\mu(B)$ is in the equation. But I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What is $R$ and what is $\mu$?

Comment: I have edited the question to include that information.

Comment: I would suggest doing it for finite intervals first, and then approximate your sets $A$ and $B$ with such intervals by Littlewood.  It might also be helpful to use the fact that $\mu((A-x)\cap B)$ is continuous, which is proved in a similar way.

Comment: You can write $\mu((A-x)\cap B)=\int_{\mathbb R} \chi_A(u-x)\chi_B(u)\,d\mu(u)$, and then see if you can use Fubini, where $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$ are the characteristic or indicator functions of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I don't understand the notation here, what do $d\mu(u)$ and $\mathbb{1}_{A}(u-x)$ mean? I know that $\mathbb{1}_{A}(x)$ takes the value $1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I think I get it. $\int \int d\mu(u)d\mu(x) =\int \int dudx$, upon conversion to the Reimann integral (when it can be done), right?