# In General, What Can be Said about $\mu(A)\mu(B)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space. What can we say about the product $\mu(A) \mu(B)$ in general? Are there any useful identities? Useful inequalities? (is this question to broad?) I'm trying to grow my toolkit as a student, and I'm curious what is out there.

The only things which I have found are (a) [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565624/int-mathbbr-mua-x-cap-bd-mu-mua-mub) on this site and (b) what is apparently called the [Brunn-Minkowski Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem). However, neither of those hold for a *general* measure space $X$. Does anyone know of any useful identities or inequalities which hold in said, more general context?